# Firebase Pub/Sub trigger multiple jobs with messages at once

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I am running a cronjob every evening to send notifications to a set of users in my database, call them 1-100. However, recently with an increase in my users, it's taking longer and longer for this job to run. Is there a way to have the pub/sub topic trigger multiple jobs, say triggering one job to handle users 1-50, and another to handle users 51-100?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just partition your users according to some bucketing scheme (maybe modulo their UID), create more pubsub topics and functions for those partitions, and send messages to those topics for each of the the partitions of users that you want to process.  So, in your main scheduled function, just send messages to each pubsub topic partition, and let the delegate functions do their work.

Also, if your haven't already, consider increasing the timeout for the main function in case it just needs more time to finish processes.  The max timeout for a Cloud Functions background trigger is 9 minutes.